# Display input then add the input to clipboard ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code I have so far. I have a function to display the users input and a separate function to copy text to clipboard. What I would like to do is the user to put and input then copy that input to the clipboard after its displayed.

```js
function CopyToClipboard () {
    var input = document.getElementById ("toClipboard");
    window.clipboardData.setData ("Text", input.value);
}
function ShowClipboardContent () {
    alert (window.clipboardData.getData ("Text"));
}
function ClearClipboard () {
    window.clipboardData.clearData ("Text");
}

function showInput() {
    var message_entered =  document.getElementById("user_input").value;

    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = message_entered;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
        <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
    </form>

    <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br />
    <label>Your input: </label>
    <p><span id='display'></span></p>

    <input id="toClipboard" value="text to clipboard"/>
    <button onclick='CopyToClipboard ()'>Copy text to clipboard</button>
    <br /><br />
    <button onclick='ShowClipboardContent ();'>Show text data in clipboard</button>
    <button onclick='ClearClipboard ();'>Clear text data from clipboard</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showInput() {
    var message_entered = document.getElementById("user_input").value;

    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = message_entered;
    document.getElementById('toClipboard').value = message_entered;
}
```

You're missing the last line in the showInput function.  I added it for you...